# Speed Up ComboBox list read

Tags: combobox, wxpython

I'm trying to use a combo box to set some strings. It works but it's really slow for values above 1200.

Here is the code:

```
import wx

listy=list()
for i in range(1200):
    listy.append(str(i))
print(listy)

class bdnomes(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(bdnomes, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(500,300))

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        pnl=wx.Panel(self)

        self.cbx1=wx.ComboBox(pnl, choices=listy, pos=(10,10))
        self.cbx1.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX,self.onSelect)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def onSelect(self, e):
        widget=e.GetEventObject()
        if isinstance(widget,wx.ComboBox):
                print(str(widget.GetValue()))

ex = wx.App()
bdnomes(None, 'Bd')
ex.MainLoop()
```

Is it possíble to speed up?

Comment: How slow?  Regardless of that answer, using a `wx.ComboBox` for more than a few dozen items is usually not a very good UI, and can be difficult to use for users.  You may want to implement some other way for the user to make the selection such as using a `wx.ListBox` ot `wx.ListCtrl`, or perhaps a series of `wx.ComboBox` that let the user do something like first select a category, then in another combo select a sub-category, and then the actual item in another combo.

Comment: Like 1 minut to load 8k lines and sometimes unresponsive after click in Arrow to choose. I'll try these other widgets.

Comment: Listbox solved the issue. Thanks.